# OpenCV: How to compare the performances of feature detectors and extractors using images of a real scene by different point of view?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, feature-extraction, feature-selection, outliers

I'm trying to build a loop closure algorithm, but before to start the development I would like to test which feature descriptor work better on a real dataset.

I have a pair of images of a corridor taken in both direction, one entering in a room and the other leaving the same room. So they represent the same scene but from 2 different (opposite) points of view.

I'm using OpenCV and I've already coded the part for the detector, the extractor and the matcher.

But now looking at the results I find that there are a lot of false matches.
How can I drop them?
I tried to use cv::FindFoundamentalMat but I'm not sure that this is the right way to do that.

---

edit

I found this paper ([ShmidtJAMRIS12](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CEwQFjAE&url=http://www.jamris.org/01_2013/saveas.php?QUEST=JAMRIS_No01_2013_P_11-20.pdf&ei=V0TpUbCnEayO7Qbr_4GYBw&usg=AFQjCNHj3hDlkYS3S4mmgQzEwRLzpBuyzA&sig2=jqa26X3HqQAm6uiSWOftAA&bvm=bv.49478099,d.ZGU&cad=rja)) that exactly does what I have in mind but I cannot understand how they choose the parameters of each detector and extractor

Answer (score 1):

Finding some kind of geometrical consistency is one of the basic ways of ensuring two matching images are the same place. A fundamental matrix may be ok, a homography may be ok if you match planar surfaces (as walls in corridors). If you work with a stream of images, you can also check if matches of consecutive images are consistent. 
Here is a paper that uses these techniques: http://webdiis.unizar.es/~dorian/dl.php?dlp=GalvezTRO12.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
You are right for the idea of the stream of images, but you know, there are way a lot of parameters for each descriptor extractor and detector.
If I check all of them with a stream of images it will take to much time...

For the first step I would like only to compare the performances on a pair of images from the same scene and a pair of images from different scene so I can skim some parameters and descriptors extractor/detector.

I'm right?